# iOS Screen recording

Tags: ios, screen-capture

I'm wondering if there is an Apple policy against screen sharing? My basic use case is similar to the mirroring feature from iPad to Apple TV, except I'm seeking to mirror the device onto a Mac (as opposed to a TV).

What I ultimately need to do is record the actions from a Mac (or PC if that works) that are taking place on an iOS device -- which includes opening the app store; so emulating is not an option. If anyone can think of a clever way to record what's happening on the iOS device, without pointing a camera at it, I'm all ears.

In case anyone comes across this, Quicktime's screen recording + Xcode's emulator should work under normal circumstances. My use case is just more demanding.

Answer (score 4):

Starting from iOS8 and Yosemite You can capture the screen of iOS device from Quicktime directly. Here's the steps:

1. Connect your iPhone, iPad or iPod touch to your Mac via a Lightning Cable.
2. Open the QuickTime app.
3. Go to File and select ‘New Movie Recording’.
4. A recording window will appear. You will a see little arrow for drop down menu in front of the record button. Click that arrow and select your iPhone.
5. Select the Mic of your iPhone if you want to record music, app/game sounds.
6. Click the Record button. Now perform the tasks on your iOS device that you want to record.
7. Once done tap the stop button and save the video.
8. Done!

---

NOTE: works only with iOS8 and Yosemite and devices with Lightning Cable.

All steps taken from: [ioshacker](http://ioshacker.com/how-to/use-quicktime-record-screen-iphone-ipad-ipod-touch-running-ios-8) website. Enter there for screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

On iOS 11, screen recording is supported natively. Here is how to use it:

- Go to Settings => Control Center and add the Screen Recording widget
- Go to the home screen by pressing the home button (or swiping up on the home bar on an iPhone X)
- Open the Control Center by swiping down from the top right corner of the screen
- Tap the record screen widget (looks like the record button on a VCR)

Answer (score 1):

Connect your iPhone with a [iPhone to VGA adaptor](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC552ZM/B) with a [VGA Capture](http://www.vgacapture.com/).  Untested.

Answer (score 1):

Cleanest way is probably to use [AirServer](http://airserver.com). You just mirror to your PC/Mac and record the iOS device's screen to disk.

1) it's wireless and 
2) Higher quality of recording than the QuickTime option on mac 
3) you can also livestream to YouTube so I thought it was good to add it as an option.
I'm on mac and I choose to do this rather than using quicktime. QuickTime is also good though if you don't care about live streaming to YouTube or better quality for recording.

Comment: I would say this is good for PC. The Mac already includes recording software to record iOS so installing extra seems less ideal to me. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/158031/recording-ipad-screen-using-quicktime As well as the answer here on QuickTime.

Comment: Yeah but 1) it's wireless and 2) Higher quality of recording 3) you can also livestream to YouTube so I thought it was good to add it as an option. I'm on mac and I choose to do this rather than using quicktime. QuickTime is also good though.

Comment: Please add that detail in an edit. +1

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone 4S and iPad 2 can do screen mirroring over HDMI with the [Apple AV Adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC953ZM/A). With an HDMI capture card, you could record directly that way. But aside from that (or with hardware other than the 4S or iPad 2), you're probably out of luck if the iOS Simulator doesn't do what you need.

Comment: I knew I should have mentioned that I refuse to buy all the gadgetry to hook it up to a TV. But thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Mateusz Szlosek answer works great. I'm answering to add an alternative. I record tons of iPad tutorials, and frequently use Pickle Studio (http://picklestud.io). Besides recording the iOS screen, Pickle Studio includes some extra features: you can include partial Mac screens and video camera. It's a bit simple, but works really well. It has some interesting filter options as well.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 11 now allows you to cleanly record your device screen complete with audio.

It will get saved to the Camera Roll where you can edit/trim it and send the final video to your computer.