# Is there a way to take a screenshot gif (screenvideo) of an iPhone interaction?

Tags: ios, xcode, video, screen-capture, screen-recording

I'd like to take a motion-recording of an interaction on an iOS device while it's plugged into a computer. (To report a bug or demonstrate a feature, without making a shakycam video with another device, i.e. my friggin' iPad )

Does Xcode or a similar tool support this?

Comment: It's built-in in iOS 11 (so you don't even need a Mac), other (older) options here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/34201/121968

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a Mac, you can connect your device to the computer and use Quicktime to capture the screen as a video. After selecting 'New Movie Recording' your device will be offered as a source.

https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/record-iphone-screen-quicktime/

Comment: This is excellent! Thank you! (Also, it looks like Kap is integrating this soon; and it's slick, free, and open-source: https://github.com/wulkano/kap/issues/71)